# Is there a better way to dynamically set Values in react-hook-form on a next.ts project?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-hook-form

I am working on a *next.ts* project in which I need to dynamically set the fields of a *react-hook-form* form. The best way I've found to type the "name" parameter in literal string is with the *as* operator, as it follows:

```
type val = "businessName";
setValue(name as val, "Some businessName");
```

but I presume that there is a more elegant way to do it that maybe escapes me.
Here's the documentation about the *setValue* function:

https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/setvalue

and here's a basic example of what I mean, any advice is welcome.

https://codesandbox.io/s/twilight-thunder-5ecnfu

Comment: Why do you need to explicitly type the `name` value? TypeScript will infer the right type for the value that you pass to `setValue` (in this case the string literal `"businessName"`).

Answer (score 0):

This is actually the correct way to change your form values. But since you are using typescript you can use type definition to set the form names.

Here is an example.

Let's say you have a form with name and email. But it might be user and email. Then you can define a type like the following.

```
  type LoginFormValues {
    name: string,
    email: string
  } | {
    user: string,
    email: string
  }
```

Then define this type with the useForm function.

```
  const {} = useForm<LoginFormValues>()
```

Now, you can have dynamic form values.

There are other ways to do what you want, but this is the most elegant way.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it is certainly useful, but I have probably explained myself wrong. I was referring to the type annotation of the "name" parameter of the _setValue_ function. Here's the documentation about what I mean: https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/setvalue

Answer (score 0):

**key as any** takes the error away and since I'm using the validation schema as the source, I'm not worried about it.

```
  const data = {
    "id": "somedata"
  }

  // Zod validation schema
  const validationSchema = z.object({
    id: z.string()
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    Object.keys(validationSchema.keyof().Values).map((key) => {
      if(key == 'xyz') return;
      data?.[key] && setValue(key as any, data[key]);
    });
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [alerts]);
```